# Entering an input prior to launching the script in console (Python, Windows)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Here is my simple script:

```
a = input('User input before pressing enter: ', )
```

Here is how my console looks like prior to launching the script:

```
C:\Users\m.povilaika\Desktop\Full> myscript.py
```

and then I would press enter to launch the script, which is where the input always appears.

Can I somehow have the input prior to pressing enter in console?

How it would look like:

```
C:\Users\m.povilaika\Desktop\Full> myscript.py my_input
```

Then I would press enter and would not need to enter the input again.

Comment: Check out the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#id1 Look at argprase

Comment: Although, you don't need `argparse` to take command-line arguments. You just need `sys.argv`. `argparse` is just to do complex parsing, which you may or may not need.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo I am looking into it.

Comment: Thanks @NiteyaShah, looking into it

Comment: @Carcigenicate do you mind showing the code for sys.argv? Thanks

Comment: @Carcigenicate, never mind my last question, it seems to work, thanks again